# What unicode format do I pass tinyxml functions that take char*?

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

When I call a tinyxml function that takes a char*, what unicode format do I need to pass it?

```
TiXmlText *element_text = new TiXmlText(string);
```

The reason is that I am using a wxString object and there is a lot of different encodings I can give it. If I just do string.c_str(), the wxstring object will query the encoding for the current locale and create a char* string in that format. Or if I do string.utf8_str(), it will pass a utf-8 string but it seems like tinyxml will not realize that it's utf-8 encoded already and reencode the utf-8 string as utf-8 (yes, the result is double utf-8 encoding). So when I write out, if I set notepad++ to show utf-8, I see:

baÄŸlam instead of bağlam.

I'd like to do the encoding myself to utf_8 (string.utf8_str()) and not have tinyxml touch it and just write it out.

How do I do this? What format does tinyxml expect to be passed in the function parameter (constructor in the above code)? The answer from testing is not utf-8 though it eventually writes it out as utf-8 if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyXML only supports UTF-8 encoding. So if you want to provide characters outside of ASCII, you must provide them in UTF-8.

Comment: This only says that tinyxml will write out utf-8. It doesn't say what the functions accept. From testing, passing utf-8 encoded char * to the function will not work.

Comment: If I pass ğlam to TiXmlText object as utf-8 (c4 9f 6c 61 6d), the value is written out to the file as (c3 84 c5 b8 6c 61 6d). Thus, tinyxml must want it in a different format because it's converting it wrong. What format though?

Comment: Ok, I'm screwing it up downstream. Because I'm serializing the xml in a special way, I am not using the SaveFile() function that tinyxml provides. In fact, I'm just using it's memory buffer which is probably in ansi or something else (need to research it). Anyways, when I use SaveFile it works perfectly so the problem is my fault. Thanks for taking the time out to help me. I am marking this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this section on http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html

> TinyXML can be compiled to use or not use STL. When using STL, TinyXML uses the std::string class, and fully supports std::istream, std::ostream, operator <<, and operator >>. Many API methods have both 'const char*' and 'const std::string&' forms.
>
> When STL support is compiled out, no STL files are included whatsoever. All the string classes are implemented by TinyXML itself. API methods all use the 'const char*' form for input.
>
> Use the compile time define TIXML_USE_STL to compile one version or the other. This can be passed by the compiler, or set as the first line of "tinyxml.h".